# cucumber command that will print out just the feature and scenario names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber

Is there a cucumber command that will print out just the feature info and the scenario names?

I recently began a project and want to print out the cucumber features and scenarios I wrote to describe the scope of the project and get it confirmed with the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `cucumber -d`?

```
$ cucumber -h
-d, --dry-run    Invokes formatters without executing the steps.
                 This also omits the loading of your support/env.rb file if it exists.
                 Implies --no-snippets.
                 Implies --dry-run --formatter pretty.
```